# $L^2$-Oscillation

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that the following property is satisfied.
$$\int\limits_{[0,1]}\int\limits_{[0,1]}|f(x)-f(y)|^2dxdy\leq \varepsilon.$$
What can I most say about $\max\limits_{[0,1]}f-\min\limits_{[0,1]}f$?

Comment: 1. Edit your inequality inserting $dxdy$, please.  2. Inequality holds for every $\varepsilon$ or fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose $f_n(x) = x^n$, with $n$ a positive integer, a quick computation shows that $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|^2 \, dx dy = \frac{2n^2}{(n+1)^2(2n+1)}$. Furthermore, $\max_{x\in [0,1]} f_n(x) - \min_{x\in [0,1]} f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$.

Hence the integral can be made arbitrarily small, yet the range is 1. So, roughly speaking, not much can be said about the range given integral bound information.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$Nothing.
We have
\begin{align*}
  \int_{[0,1]^2} \abs{f(x) - f(y)}^2\, d(x,y)
   &\le 
     \int_{[0,1]^2} \abs{f(x)}^2\,d(x,y) + \int_{[0,1]^2} 2\abs{f(x)}\abs{f(y)}\, d(x,y) + \int_{[0,1]^2} \abs{f(y)}^2\, d(x,y)\\
    &= \|f\|^2 + 2\|f\|^2 + \|f\|^2\\
    &= 4\|f\|^2 
\end{align*}
That is, your term will be small if $\|f\|^2$ is small. Now let $f_n$ be a smooth, positive function with $\max f_n = n$, $\min f_n = 0$, $\mathrm{supp}\, f_n \subseteq [0, \frac 1{n^3}]$. Then $\|f\|^2 \le n^2 \cdot \frac 1{n^3} = \frac 1n$, but $\max f_n - \min f_n = n$.

Comment: I dont think you can say that $|f|^{2}$ is small.you can say it may be small, but from the given condition you cant get that implication(atleast not directly)